# Can't multiply 2 var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write my first java script and need some help.

I need to  multiply some var, `var sum_fin = 2 * sum_res;` (28 row of script), but can't do these - display show error. What's wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var sum_min = 2000;
    var sum_max = 100000;
    var sum_step = 100;

    $( ".sum_slid" ).slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 7000,
        min: sum_min,
        max: sum_max,
        step: sum_step,

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            sum_res =  ui.value;
            $( ".sum_res" ).html( sum_res );
            $( "#fn-sl-dig-take" ).html( sum_res );

        },

        change: function(event, ui) { 
            $('.sum_in').attr('value', ui.value);
            $( "#fn-sl-dig-take" ).attr('value', ui.value);
        }
    });

    var k_sum = 0.1;
    var sum_fin = 2 * sum_res;
    $( ".sum_min" ).html( sum_min );
    $( ".sum_max" ).html( sum_max );
    $( ".sum_step" ).html( sum_step );
    $( ".k_sum" ).html( k_sum );
    $( ".sum_fin" ).html( sum_fin );
});
```

Comment: go thru a tutorial

Comment: Read up on variable scope... And well.. Programming. It's a good advice to go through a proper tutorial. Spend at least a day or two learning about the basics in Javascript. In this case the problem is variable scope - to begin with.

Comment: There's only javascript code in your fiddle.  The accompanying html code needs to be there so we can run it and see what's going on with your code.

Comment: For future reference: it helps out **a lot** if you tell us what the error message says. Error messages are the number one way for you to find out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes, i have html and all work good, aside one thing - 
var sum_fin doen't shown on website. Multyply doesn't work.

May by var sum_res doens't public as in php?

Comment: @Den "var sum_fin doen't shown on website" is not an error message. It's a bad description of the problem. Check your console (hit F12 on Windows or Cmd+Opt+I on Mac) and look at the error messages.

Comment: Consol said "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

I output var value to html as `<span class="k_sum">1</span>`. All vars work correctly aside sum_fin

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare `sum_res` anywhere which is why you will receive an error when running this code.

Comment: In php for these needed to wrote global $var; and what about java? 

I found this article, but can't make my `sum_res` global
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: can you help? i doesn't know how to do this